# Problem iteration through folders and finding the timestamp for specific files

Tags: python, datetime, os.path

I wrote a function i Python, which iterates through a root folder, which contains different folders within folders.

These foldes contains a lot of different files, but i am particulary only looking for the PNG files within the folders that was created within the last 24 hours.

I wrote this code, but unfortunately i get an error..

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolder):

   # if(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(root)).strftime("%Y") == "2021"):
        for file in files:  

            if file.endswith(".png"):
                time = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(root)).strftime("%Y")

                print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))
```

Apperently when i try to call:

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))
```

I get "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The file was not found: '001-001-001.png'

and i dont understand this, "not found" part, when it returns the name to me in the error message???

If i write root inside the function instead, i will get a result and timestamps are returned, but those are not the ones i need.

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))
```

I was thinking of doing this:

```
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolder):

   # if(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(root)).strftime("%Y") == "2021"):
        for file in files:  

            if file.endswith(".png") and datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d") == datetime.now().strftime("%Y:%m:%d"):
                time = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(root)).strftime("%Y")

                print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))
```

Where i will compare the png files timestamp to the current time and check whether they are older than 24 hours/ a day.. but unfortunately i get an error due to the code not being able to take "file" as an input in the getmtime() function..

I hope that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the script use the expected directory?

You can check the directories with:

```py
print("current directory: ", os.getcwd())
print("root: ", root)
print("current file: ", file)
```

Your initial script should work if you run it from the PNG folder.

Or you use the complete path to the files, for example like this:

```py
timestamp = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, file))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))
```